# Use index file to export .tsx modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

It's a common thing to create a index.js file in an React application with the only purpose to export several modules, in order to avoid having too many import statements on other components. This can be done by:

**index.js**

```
export { Credits } from './Credits.js';
export { SocialMedia } from './SocialMedia.js';
```

**any module that might use those exports:**

```
import * as var_name from index.js
```

And this is very nice. It wraps exports into a single file. However, when I changed my project to React with typescript, I found that `.tsx` files cannot be exported like that. The image below is the error I got after changing the project to typescript and the extensions became `.tsx`

[image]

Is there a way of 'bundle' export React `.tsx` files with the structure shown above? If not, what is the simplest way of centralizing `.tsx` files export?

**My webpack.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ["sass-loader"]
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that isn't possible? Perhaps your Webpack/... config is configured to use `index.tsx` (and not `index.ts`) as entry point?

Comment: The only configuration in my webpack is about sass-loader, to use .scss files as modules. I'll updated it in the question. I'm fairly new to typescript. Is it necessary to add configurations to webpack in order to do this?

Comment: That's a very small `webpack.config.js`. Did you omit anything, or are you using a certain framework such as `react-scripts`?

Comment: Indeed I am. The project was wrapped with create-react-app --template typscript.

Comment: I thought `create-react-app` doesn't allow you to have a custom `webpack.config.js`, does your `.scss` rule even work? _and if so, isn't it by default included in CRA perhaps?_ If you can actually use that `webpack.config.js`, then look up Webpack config to change the entry point.

Comment: Another thought - does it work if you omit the file extension entirely, say `import { thing } from './<folder name>'`? Most projects I've worked on omit extensions from JS/TS/JSX/TSX imports and Webpack figures out which file to use.

Comment: @TimErnsberger, I went back to code and forgot to get back to the question. Yes. Omitting the extension did work. That's how I'm using those index.ts files

Comment: Glad to hear that worked. I'll submit it as an answer to the question in case anyone comes here in the future and glosses over the comments section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can definitely use the same style of having an index file to group up exports for a whole folder. The simplest way around your problem would be to omit the file extension (assuming you only have one "index" file in the folder).

For example, let's say you have a component in 'common/Example.tsx':

```
import React from 'react'

export const Example = () => (<div>I'm an example component</div>)
```

You can then export it in an index file 'common/index.tsx':

```
export { Example } from './Example'
```

And import it from somewhere else, e.g. 'App.tsx':

```
import { Example } from './common'
```